# How to toggle between values in a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React hook I call useToggles that I use for various checkboxes and radio buttons in my app. So far I have been able to get away with something like the following:

```
const useToggles = (initialValues = {}) => {
  const [toggleValues, setToggleValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleToggle = e => {
    const name = e.currentTarget.attributes.name.value;
    const value = toggleValues[e.currentTarget.attributes.name.value];

    setToggleValues(values => ({ ...values, [name]: !value }));
  };

  return {
    toggleValues,
    setToggleValues,
    handleToggle,
  };
};

export default useToggles;
```

An example checkbox component:

```
<CheckBox
   checked={toggleValues.gluten || false}
   label="Gluten"
   onChange={handleToggle}
   name="gluten"
 />
```

So although my "toggleValues" object starts off as {}, any time a checkbox is checked, it populates the object. So we might have:

```
{
  gluten: true,
  soy: false
}
```

Because there's only one layer to this object, spreading out the values and using `[name]: !value` to flip the Boolean value will work.

However, this falls apart when there is the need for more organization. On another page, I have several groups of checkboxes, the values of which I will need to group together to populate individual database fields. To handle this, I've added a layer of organization to the checkboxes:

```
 <CheckBox
      checked={toggleValues.dietType.paleo || ''}
      label="Paleo"
      onChange={handleToggle}
      name="dietType.paleo"
    />
```

We have used this method of organization elsewhere in our app in order to group data, and have parsed the string with dot-object. Example from u`seFormValues()`:  `dot.str(e.target.name, value, tmp)`;

This method does not work with `useToggles` because we rely on previously existing data in the `toggleValues` object. Using dot-object consistently creates new layers of the object every time you click the checkbox. But I haven't found a way of using [name] to select a second or third level of an object.

To visualize this, what I need to be able to do is take this object and flip the value of paleo to true based on the function receiving the name "dietType.paleo":

```
{
    dietType: {
      paleo: true;
    },
    intolerances: {}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use currying and pass the checkbox group name as parameter to `handleToggle`:

```
const handleToggle = sub => e => {
  const name = e.currentTarget.attributes.name.value;
  if (!sub) setToggleValues({ ...toggleValues, [name]: !toggleValues[name] });
  else {
    const newSub = { ...toggleValues[sub], [name]: !toggleValues[sub][name] };
    setToggleValues({ ...toggleValues, [sub]: newSub });
  }
};
```

Now use `onChange={handleToggle()}` for the top level and `onChange={handleToggle("dietType")}` for the paleo checkbox.

**Edit:**
Another way is to check if the `name` has a period in it and branch accordingly:

```
const handleToggle = e => {
  const name = e.currentTarget.attributes.name.value;
  if (!~name.indexOf("."))
    setToggleValues({ ...toggleValues, [name]: !toggleValues[name] });
  else {
    const [sub, prop] = name.split(".");
    const newSub = { ...toggleValues[sub], [prop]: !toggleValues[sub][prop] };
    setToggleValues({ ...toggleValues, [sub]: newSub });
  }
};
```

This way you can keep your existing JSX 1:1.

Comment: Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-smoke-cksug

Comment: Thanks, this worked! One additional note is the "name" attribute needed to be changed from `name: "dietType.paleo"` to simply `name: "paleo"`

Comment: @ipenguin67 Right, this made me rethink my approach though; I added an alternate version to my answer that let's you keep your JSX.